# Chart.js migration from v2 to v4: tick "label" paddings behave differently how can I achieve the same layout?

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm trying to migrate Chart.js from v2 to v4. But I'm facing an issue with the padding/position of the tick label.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can achieve the same result as on v2?
I've also tried some hacky stuff with the labelBackdrop but that doesn't work either.

---

## Chart.js v2

Chart looks like this (ticks have "padding: -20", to be inset).
[image]

[image: Edit blue-rain-52lpqr]

---

## Chart.js v4

When using v4 with the same options, my chart looks like this and the tick labels are hidden.

[image]

When doing "padding: 20" the whole chart gets "padded" like this:

[image]

And "padding: 0" results in no padding around the label.

[image]

[image: Edit crazy-kate-zr9jnc]

---